# pyplot axes with minimum range but changing limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the power of a signal which has according to the range of frequency a different power. Therefore I want to have the y-axis set automatically, but it still should have a decent size (not only the range of the min and max of the noise).

Of course I can set `plt.ylim` but then I am fixed to one specific range.

Comment: Since there is no `plt.decent_size()` command, you probably want to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want that the range of the y-axis has for example a size of 10 units, but the limits should get chosen automatically.

Comment: What would be the criteria for choosing the limits then?

Comment: The limits should be chosen so that the signal is shown. When I just set it to auto, before you have a proper signal, the noise looks like big peaks because of the small limit range.

Comment: So does that mean that you want something like `[min(data)-offset, max(data)+offset]`, where `offset` is a fixed value and `data` can evolve in time?

Comment: Maybe rather mean(data)±offset, else you don't get constant 10 units? Or (min+max)/2±offset? Is this question about an animation?

Comment: Yeah it's kind of an animation. But the way with the datapoint and offset could work. Thanks.